# Drawing simple math graph in c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing

I need to make math graph like this:

[image]

I store f(x), g(x), h(x) coefficients in arrays same like (x,y) of that 3 points.

What is the simplest way to draw it in WPF C#? Do you have any advice? Thank you